# WMI Search Wildcard returns nothing

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

**EDIT:** Added oScope

When I run my query without wildcards, it returns what I expect it to. But if I modify the query just a little, it doesn't throw errors. Instead, it just doesn't return anything, giving me a false-negative.

The code below returns ZERO rows:

```
    ManagementScope oScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + txtHostName + 
        "\\root\\CIMV2", oConn);

    string wheresub = "FileName Like '%myfile%'";

    ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE (" +
        wheresub + ") AND (Drive = 'C:' OR Drive = 'D:' OR Drive = 'E:')");

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oScope, oQuery);

    Log("Searching...");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        FilesFound++;
        Log(String.Format("--> {0}{1}{2}.{3}", queryObj["Drive"], queryObj["Path"], queryObj["FileName"], queryObj["Extension"]));
    }
    if (FilesFound > 0)
    {
        Log(" " + FilesFound + " files found.");
    }
    else
    {
        Log(" Clean.");
    }
```

This slice of code always returns "Clean." But if I change ONE line, to find a specific file, it finds the one specific file:

```
string wheresub = "FileName = 'PROCID_myfile_1234'";
```

I need the wildcard version so that I can find all of the possible files, not just a specific one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes and adding either %myfile or myfile% so you would want something like this string wheresub = "FileName Like %myFile"; or change %myFile to %myFile% try it out I get RPC errors when launching your code also what version of Windows are you on..? there is an error / bug in CIM_DATAFILE you get something when not ran in Adminstrator mode vs running in Administrator mode here is the reference http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954061

Comment: - - also where are you defining the oScope variable I have mine declared as ManagementScope oScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\ComputerName\\root\\cimv2"); I get errors when running your query but if I change it to Select * from CIM_DataFile i get results

Comment: Yes, that's the same scope I have. I just didn't copy/paste it.

Comment: check out that Microsoft site in the above link it mentions some bugs about CIM_DataFile

Comment: I test it "has is" it's really long, but it works fine for me with  wildcard (it's even not case sensitive)